# what is best way to start bitcoin exchange @India

Tags: india

we are bunch of Full stack developer whom wants to start bitcoin trading platform @india 
- with very low cost 
- easy process
- easy to use
- Top most security
- super fast

tech we will use for creating platform 
- nodejs
- mondodb
- vuejs

Comment: If you need to ask that question on stack exchange, I don't think you should be running an exchange.

Comment: i did't said we are running exchange , i said we are about to create one ..

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

If I were setting up an exchange, I would look for a back-end that already exists, with a front-end that I could "white label".

Firstly, I am a developer that works with Bitshares, so my advice can be considered tainted. In my position, I know the code. I do not necessarily know the business. So take everything I say and place it in context.

Secondly, I know very little about the intricacies of laws in India, and I never encourage illegal activity. So make sure you what you do is legal within your jurisdiction.

Now, on with the show...

Bitshares: The Code

Bitshares-core is an open-source (MIT licensed) blockchain project that is based on DPoS (Distributed Proof of Stake).

Bitshares: The Network

Scattered around the world are "Witnesses". They take care of making sure the transactions coming through are legitimate. Think of them as "miners" in the Bitcoin world.

Where you may fit in:

What some have done is provide a "front-end" to the Bitshares blockchain. They provide the customer service, the wallet, the website, etc. Bitshares takes care of the network pieces.

I would strongly consider building it with Bitshares as the back-end. It provides "stablecoins" that allow fiat-like balances to sit there without exposing it to the volatility of crypto currency. It provides a trading platform with some existing trading pairs, and you can create your own. There are open-source front-ends that you can "white label"

Answer (score 0):

I think Bitcoin transaction is illegal in India, You can not convert Bitcoin to INR.

Check below link,
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/personal-finance-news/your-bank-will-not-allow-you-to-buy-bitcoins-anymore/articleshow/63627123.cms

RBI, while announcing its first bi-monthly monetary policy for the FY 2018-19, has announced that any entity regulated by them such as banks, wallets etc. shall not deal with or provide services to any individual or business entities for buying or selling of cryptocurrency such as bitcoins. If banks, e-wallets and any other entities regulated by RBI are not allowed to facilitate sale or purchase of cryptocurrencies, obviously individuals will not be able to transfer money from their bank account ..